# Is it possible to dockerize the drools expert and drools workbench?

Tags: docker, drools

We are working on a client requirement to implement the rule engine. Our client wants to have the workbench as well so that business user can also make changes to the rules.

We have three components in the architecture:

1. Maven repo which has the jar file
2. Web service which takes input passes to rule session and sends back result. This also interacts with the maven repo.
3. Workbench which interacts with the Maven repo to update the rules.

Now my queries are:

1. Can all these three components be deckerized ?
2. Is it ok to go with community edition of drools or enterprise ?
3. Please provide any case studies if you have used the enterprise edition.

Regards
S

Answer (score 1):

### Posted on behalf of Roger Martinez Palleja

Yes, it is possible. There already exist docker images (for community versions) for both jBPMN and Drools workbenches that already provide a similar scenario.

You can find the docker images here:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/drools-workbench-showcase/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/jbpm-workbench-showcase/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/kie-server-showcase/

The sources for those images, that can be useed as examples for building your owns, are here:

- https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/drools
- https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/jbpm

As you can read on the different readme files, you can run different workbench docker containers and different kie-server containers as well  and all get connected by using docker linking, as the example command for kie-server image describes.

In those jboss showcase images, the different kie-servers are using the workbench container's internal maven repository to fetch the maven artifacts, not sure if it's your concrete situation, but you can easily change the maven repository to use on the different kie-server container's as well by using environment variables or just creating your own docker image on top of the jboss ones.